# What is the use of `webView.getSolidColor();` in Android webView?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I was trying to get the theme color of current website loaded in webView. I found this function called `webView.getSolidColor();` which returns the `int color` type value. What this function is for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this function "Returns the known solid color background for this view" and Override this if your view is known to always be drawn on top of a solid color background, and needs to draw fading edges.